# Floated right button in navbar jumps to the next line for XS displays

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have simple navbar with one button floated to the right, when I change display size to XS(phone view) button jumps to the next line, how can I keep it floated right and in the same line with brand name ?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BjjBase.com</a>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn navbar-right">+ Submit Event</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.bootply.com/tZN98fGOmL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navbar-header` changes to 100% width at 768 pixels or less (xs), so you could remove it to prevent the vertical stacking..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BjjBase.com</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn pull-right">+ Submit Event</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

http://bootply.com/n1V0BBnVRJ